# Pattern Maching IO variables in haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads

Currently I have a function `getFP :: IO [String] -> Maybe (FilePath)`. What I want to do is something equivalent for `getFP [] = Nothing` if the argument was a non IO string. How could I do this? Thank you :p

Comment: You can not "unwrap" a value from an `IO`: an `IO a` is not a really a state, it is a recipe to generate an `a`, so the `IO a` is basically a procedure to get an `a`, not the `a` itself.

Comment: The beginner's instinct with `IO` is to try and convert IO things to "normal" things, so that you can pass them to the functions you're already familiar with. `do` syntax can make it look like you're doing that, but it never actually does it. You **can** use all the "normal" functions you're familiar with on IO things, but to do so what you actually need to look for is not ways to convert the IO things to "normal" things, but ways to convert the "normal" functions to IO versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IO [String]` is an action that can produce `[String]`. There’s no way to convert it to a pure value `Maybe FilePath`, but you can easily combine it with a pure function to get another action. One way is to write it out in `do` notation. For example, suppose you want the first path:

```
getFP :: IO [String] -> IO (Maybe FilePath)
getFP action = do
  strings <- action
  case strings of
    path : _ -> pure (Just path)
    [] -> pure Nothing
```

This might be used like `getFP loadPaths` where `loadPaths` is some action like `lines <$> readFile "paths.txt"` that returns a list of file paths. However, it’s more common to take a pure value as an argument instead of an action, if you’re just going to run that action immediately anyway.

```
getFP :: [String] -> IO (Maybe FilePath)
getFP strings =
  case strings of
    path : _ -> pure (Just path)
    [] -> pure Nothing
```

That would be called as `getFP =<< loadPaths`.

Now there’s no need for `IO` in `getFP`, since the only `IO` action it uses is `pure`.

```
getFP :: [String] -> Maybe FilePath
getFP strings =
  case strings of
    path : _ -> Just path
    [] -> Nothing
```

This can be used like `getFP <$> loadPaths`. (Furthermore, in this example it’s now equivalent to the standard function `listToMaybe` from `Data.List`.)